# int not equal to string

Tags: java, if-statement, int, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write if statements that set conditions that if user input is anything but integers, it will print out a message and exit. I tried == and != string and stuff like that to no avail.

Any help is appreciated
Avery

```
    System.out.println("What is the reserve price? ");
    int reserve = scanner.nextInt();


    System.out.println("What is the bid of Person 1? ");
    int p1 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the bid of Person 2? ");
    int p2 = scanner.nextInt();



    if (p1 < reserve && p2 < reserve){
        System.out.println("No one wins because the reserve price of $"+ reserve+ " was not met.");
        System.exit(0);
    }else if (p1 > p2){
        System.out.println("Person 1 wins for $"+p1+".");
    }else if (p2 > p1){
        System.out.println("Person 2 wins for $"+p2+".");
    }
    if (p1==p2){
        System.out.println("It's a tie at $"+p1+".");
    }
```

Comment: check `scanner.hasNextInt()`

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to make sure that if the user enters a letter instead of numbers, to prevent an error with an if statement, or even a do while loop. I'm just curious how that would work. Thanks

Comment: hasNextInt() method of Scanner class checks whether user entered an int or not.Just use it in if block and then assign the value returned by the nextInt() method to the proper variable inside the if block.

Comment: @HarshDave and if the user enters something that is not a `int` what is going to happen?

Comment: @AveryGreenlees if the value entered is an int the method returns true and for any other type of value input it returns false.

Comment: See the solution to similar question for which this question is marked duplicate, you will get perfect solution.